# Consulta id mais vezes repetido

Tags: php, sql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma `user` e uma outra `visitas`. Na tabela `visitas` eu guardo o ID do utilizador que foi visitado e quem visitou.

Como fazer uma consulta onde me saiam os utilizadores por ordem de mais numero de visitas? Eu não guardo o total em lado nenhum

Alguma dica?

Comment: Não sei como está a estrutura mas acredito que um `count()` com um `group by` resolva.

Comment: Edite a pergunta para incluir os detalhes importantes. Por exemplo: o que é uma visita? um usuário visita outro? Tem uma linha por visita pra cada utilizador? Se vc fornecer o modelo ER das tabelas, talvez alguém consiga responder diretamente com a expressão SQL que possa te ajudar. Caso contrário, muitas interações de comentários são necessários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta um select com função totalizadora

```
select userid, count(*)
from visitas
group by userid
order by 2 desc
```

Para ordenar use um `order by`, assim os dados aparecem com os users mais visitados em primeiro lugar.